# How can my TeamCity plugin detect if the build is private?

Tags: plugins, teamcity

I implement the following interface in my notification plugin:

- BuildServerListener

Then I implement this method so I can report failed builds:

- public void buildFinished(SRunningBuild sRunningBuild)

I don't want to generate a notification when the failed build is a private build. The following docs detail a value I can check to determine is the build is private:

- BUILD_IS_PERSONAL in http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters

My questions is how do I get access to the value of BUILD_IS_PERSONAL from my buildFinished() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! Found it:

```
@Override
public void buildFinished(SRunningBuild sRunningBuild) {
    if (sRunningBuild.getBuildType().isPersonal()) return;
    . . .
}
```